# State is not updated when testing with UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to UI test my Jetpack compose app, but I am running into all kinds of problems. This is my screen:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val x = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Button(onClick = {
        x.value = true
    }) {
        Text(text = "Click me: ${x.value}")
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when I start up the app and press the button, it changes the state and recomposes the view. However, when running this simple test, nothing happens when I or the test presses the button:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun justTest() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Click me: false").performClick()
    }
}
```

The view isn't recomposed, which means the text remains the same. You can clone my demo project here and see it for yourself: https://github.com/Jasperav/InstrumentalTest.

It also takes 46 seconds to complete the test, which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give Compose time to do the update:

```
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Click me: false").performClick()
        composeTestRule.waitForIdle()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Click me: true").assertExists()
```

This test succeeds. Without the `waitForIdle`, it fails.

Comment: Is there any reason it still takes 45 seconds?

Comment: @J.Doe Blame Android, I guess? When I run the same test with Compose Desktop, it completes in a second or two.